# How to specify dt.week to use north american week number in dataframe pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I specify dt.week to use north american week number?

*2019 Calendar:*

[image]

For example: **Date -> 01.01.2020 is Week 1 of 2020 / 31.12.2019 is Week 53 of 2019**

```
df['Week'] = df['Induction Date'].dt.week.astype(str).str.zfill(2)
```

Result:

```
             SENDER_NAME     Induction Date       InductionPlant   Week
0          b'XXXXXXXXXXXX'     2020-01-03          b'XXXXXXXXXX'     01
8910353    b'XXXXXXXXXXXX'     2019-12-31         b'XXXXXXXXXXX'     01
```

Comment: see if this [converting a pandas date to week number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31181295/converting-a-pandas-date-to-week-number) helps.

Comment: See if this [helps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55889766/pandas-datetime-week-not-as-expected/55890652#55890652)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df['Week'] = df['Date'].dt.strftime('%U').astype(np.int) + 1
```

**Output**:

```
   SENDER_NAME        Induction       Date  InductionPlant  Week
0            0  b'XXXXXXXXXXXX' 2020-01-03   b'XXXXXXXXXX'     1
1      8910353  b'XXXXXXXXXXXX' 2019-12-31  b'XXXXXXXXXXX'    53
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
# Add this if "Induction Date" is not yet in pandas datetime format
# df["Induction Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Induction Date"])

df['Week'] = df['Induction Date'].dt.to_period('W-SAT').dt.week.astype(str).str.zfill(2)
```

With `.dt.to_period('W-SAT')`, you're specifying when a week should end, in this case Saturday.

Result looks like this:

```
+------------------+--------+
| Induction Date   |   Week |
|------------------+--------|
| 2019-12-27       |     52 |
| 2019-12-28       |     52 |
| 2019-12-29       |     01 |
| 2019-12-30       |     01 |
| 2019-12-31       |     01 |
| 2020-01-01       |     01 |
| 2020-01-02       |     01 |
| 2020-01-03       |     01 |
| 2020-01-04       |     01 |
| 2020-01-05       |     02 |
+------------------+--------+
```

Comment: 31.12.2019 should be Week 53 of 2019

Comment: Your screenshot contradicts that, indicating that 31.12.2019 is week 1. In the case that 31.12.2019 should be week 53, @NYC Coder 's solution works

Comment: Sorry about that, I just wanted to show a calendar example