# Get all YEAR and WEEK combinations between a given date and today in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to get a list of all YEAR and WEEK combinations between a given date and today in pandas.

I almost succeded, but pandas dt.year and dt.week doesn't return the desired value for the date "2019-12-31".

It is a YEAR=2019 and WEEK=1 according to the above methods, whereas it should return YEAR=2020 and WEEK=1.

What is the most optimal way to improve the below code to account for this case of WEEK=1 occurring in the previous year?

```
import datetime
from datetime import date
import pandas as pd
base = datetime.date.today()
d1=date(2019,1,1)
delta=base-d1

monday1 = (base - datetime.timedelta(days=base.weekday()))
monday2 = (d1 - datetime.timedelta(days=d1.weekday()))
number_of_weeks_between = int((monday1 - monday2).days / 7)

date_list = [base - datetime.timedelta(days=x*7) for x in range(number_of_weeks_between+1)]
date_list = pd.DataFrame(date_list, columns =['Date'])
date_list['Date'] = date_list['Date'].astype('datetime64[ns]')
date_list['YEAR'] = date_list['Date'].dt.year
date_list['WEEK'] = date_list['Date'].dt.week
```

EDIT: The below code works as expected:

```
import datetime
from datetime import date
import pandas as pd
base = datetime.date.today()
d1=date(2019,1,1)
delta=base-d1

monday1 = (base - datetime.timedelta(days=base.weekday()))
monday2 = (d1 - datetime.timedelta(days=d1.weekday()))
number_of_weeks_between = int((monday1 - monday2).days / 7)

date_list = [base - datetime.timedelta(days=x*7) for x in range(number_of_weeks_between+1)]
year_list = [x.isocalendar()[0] for x in date_list]
month_list = [x.isocalendar()[1] for x in date_list]
date_list = pd.DataFrame(
          {'Date': date_list,
           'YEAR': year_list,
           'MONTH': month_list
                         })
date_list['Date'] = date_list['Date'].astype('datetime64[ns]')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas datetime week not as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55889766/pandas-datetime-week-not-as-expected)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get YEAR=2020 and WEEK=1 for "2019-12-31", you can try to replace the last 2 lines of your codes by taking the ISO Calendar year and week by the following:

```
date_list['YEAR'] = date_list['Date'].dt.isocalendar().year
date_list['WEEK'] = date_list['Date'].dt.isocalendar().week
```

**Result:**

```
date_list[date_list['Date'] == '2019-12-31']


         Date  YEAR  WEEK
88 2019-12-31  2020     1
```

Comment: Your two line replacement didn't work (I got an error), but I used the isocalendar() in a different way and it worked (see edit), so thank you for the help.

Comment: @Cowboy_Owl  Oh, really ?  I copied your code and run with the modified 2 lines to arrive at the result I shown here.  Maybe some other setup difference between our programming environments.   Anyway, it's good you came up with a modified codes that work for you based on the hint here.